# How to Add records in DB with foreign key relatationship using .Net core web Api and EF core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-5.0

I am developing Web Api CRUD repository pattern using multiple tables with Primary and Foreign key relation and for each table while inserting using separate [HttpPost] method. But how to insert(post) the records in child tables with foreign key Id property.

EmpVaccineDetail Model :

```
    public partial class EmpVaccineDetail
    {
    public EmpVaccineDetail()
    {
        CovidInfectionDetails = new HashSet<CovidInfectionDetail>();
        VaccineDoses = new HashSet<VaccineDose>();
    }

    public int EmpVaccineDetailId { get; set; }
    public string VaccineType { get; set; }
    public int UniqueHealthId { get; set; }
    public int BeneficiaryId { get; set; }
    public string VaccinationStatus { get; set; }
    public bool DoYouWantToReportCovid { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CovidInfectionDetail> CovidInfectionDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<VaccineDose> VaccineDoses { get; set; }
}
```

VaccineDose Model :

```
    public partial class VaccineDose
    {
    public int VaccineDoseId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfVaccine { get; set; }
    public string VaccineOrganizedBy { get; set; }
    public bool? Reimbursed { get; set; }
    public Guid? CoWinCertificateUploadFileId { get; set; }
    public string HospitalName { get; set; }
    public Guid? ReceiptUploadFileId { get; set; }
    public string VaccineDoseType { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey]
    public int EmpVaccineDetailId { get; set; }

    public virtual EmpVaccineDetail EmpVaccineDetail { get; set; }
}
```

VaccineDetailsRepository :

```
    public class VaccineDetailsRepository : IVaccineDetails
   {
    private readonly PeopleWorksContext _peopleWorksContext;
    public VaccineDetailsRepository(PeopleWorksContext peopleWorksContext)
    {
        _peopleWorksContext = peopleWorksContext;
    }

    public async Task<EmpVaccineDetail> Add(EmpVaccineDetail empVaccineDetail)
    {
        await _peopleWorksContext.EmpVaccineDetails.AddAsync(empVaccineDetail);
        await _peopleWorksContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return empVaccineDetail;
    }
   }
```

VaccineDosesRepository :

```
    public class VaccineDosesRepository : IVaccineDoses
{
    private readonly PeopleWorksContext _peopleWorksContext;
    public VaccineDosesRepository(PeopleWorksContext peopleWorksContext)
    {
        _peopleWorksContext = peopleWorksContext;
    }
    public async Task<VaccineDose> Add(VaccineDose vaccineDose)
    {
        await _peopleWorksContext.VaccineDoses.AddAsync(vaccineDose);
        await _peopleWorksContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return vaccineDose;
    }
}
```

Controller :

```
    public class VaccineDetailsController : ControllerBase
    {
    private readonly IVaccineDetails _vaccineDetails;
    private readonly IVaccineDoses _vaccineDoses;
    public VaccineDetailsController(IVaccineDetails vaccineDetails, IVaccineDoses 
    vaccineDoses)
    {
        _vaccineDetails = vaccineDetails;
        _vaccineDoses = vaccineDoses;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("VaccineDetails/AddVaccineDetail")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddVaccineDetail(EmpVaccineDetail empVaccineDetail)
    {
        try
        {
            await _vaccineDetails.Add(empVaccineDetail);
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("VaccineDetails/AddVaccineDose")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddVaccineDose(VaccineDose vaccineDose)
    {
        try
        {
            await _vaccineDoses.Add(vaccineDose);
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex);
        }
    }
   }
```

I added the data in the 1st table but while inserting in the 2nd table how do i pass the foreign key property. Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: Can you show the views pls? It is hard to understand what data  are you trying  to post.

Comment: Hi Serve, there is no view pages. I am testing this on Postman. You can see the Models properties, that is what I am trying to post.

Comment: Basically: get it from the database and post it. It's not clear what keeps you from doing that because we don't see the content of the posted object.

Comment: Hi, @GertArnold, while Adding the [AddVaccineDetail] i am passing this Json content


`{
    "EmpVaccineDetailId":1,
    "VaccineType": "Test",
    "UniqueHealthId":"111",
    "BeneficiaryId":"222",
    "VaccinationStatus":"Fully Vaccinated",
    "DoYouWantToReportCovid": false
}`

But when i will Post [AddVaccineDose] this, how i am going to pass that 'EmpVaccineDetailId' property with foreign key relation. 
This is what my confusion is,

Comment: Posting `EmpVaccineDetailId` is not harder than posting `DateOfVaccine` and other properties. As I said: get the value from the database and post it.

Comment: @@GertArnold, so can i send like this, is this the correct way, or i have to pass the `EmpVaccineDetailId` from code side?



```{
    "DateOfVaccine":"2021-07-04",
    "VaccineOrganizedBy":"Self",
    "Reimbursed":false,
    "HospitalName":"XYZ",
    "VaccineDoseType":"First Dose",
    "EmpVaccineDetailId":3
}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While hitting this **VaccineDetails/AddVaccineDose** url simply pass EmpVaccineDetailId through json.

```
{
    "DateOfVaccine ": "2021-05-25 00:52:29.5086347",
    .............
     ............
    "EmpVaccineDetailId ":1
}
```

Make sure you have EmpVaccineDetail data with EmpVaccineDetailId = 1. The relationship between VaccineDose and EmpVaccineDetail is one-to-many and EF Core will bind them automatically.

Comment: Hi @RafidShahriar, Thanks  for your response. so everytime when i post 'VaccineDetails/AddVaccineDose' this i have to pass this Json with EmpVaccineDetailId or is there any other way to pass that foreign key ID? Thanks

`{
    "VaccineDoseId":2,
    "DateOfVaccine":"2021-07-02",
    "VaccineOrganizedBy":"Self",
    "Reimbursed":false,
    "HospitalName":"Abcd",
    "VaccineDoseType":"First Dose",
    "EmpVaccineDetailId":1
}`

Comment: This is the conventional way to pass the foreign key. Also, you can pass the whole EmpVaccineDetail model inside JSON. But that is another case. If you have confusion you can follow this link:  https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/conventions-in-ef-core.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reference. i appreciate it. 
One more thing if i want to Get the data from both the table how can i get that.
I am using this but i am getting error. please help

Comment: Repository code ::

` public async Task<List<EmpVaccineDetail>> GetAll()
        {
            //return await _peopleWorksContext.EmpVaccineDetails.ToListAsync();
            var vaccineDetails = await _peopleWorksContext.EmpVaccineDetails
                          .Include(v => v.VaccineDoses)
                          .ToListAsync();
            return vaccineDetails;
        }`

Comment: Controller code ::


`        public async Task<IActionResult> GetVaccineDetails()
        {
            try
            {
                return Ok(await _vaccineDetails.GetAll());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex);
            }
        }`

Comment: Check your controller code. GetAll method return a List of objects. But your GetVaccineDetails controller return type is Task<IActionResult>. which can return single object. Change your controller return type to Task<IEnumerable<EmpVaccineDetail>> .